# What are some books about the effect of childhood experiences on adult life?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request

I would like to read some books about the effects of childhood experiences on the adult life. For an example, somewhere I read that adult males who had an aggressive father they are usually not aggressive (because they find it repulsive and inhumane), and also, they are not able to show anger in the proper dose when needed. The example may not be accurate but I hope I conveyed what I mean.
I have a PhD (not in neuroscience or psychology) so I think I can manage even a bit more academic oriented books. However, it would be nice to have some books suitable to average layman person too. 
It would be nice someone could read such a book and by comparison to themselves realize that some trait of them is not actually normal and should be fixed.

Comment: These types of questions are at risk of being closed (too broad/opinion based). However, I believe this question might have the right amount of specificity for this to work. Let's see how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

There are many books (both academic and non-academic) available on Adverse Childhood Experiences (ACEs), a growing area of research focused on how traumatic childhood experiences affect health and well-being in later life. A quick search for ACEs on Google or Amazon will yield many results.

Comment: Welcome to the Psych & Neuroscience SE!  This answer could be improved by links to more information on ACEs, or identifying specific books that are important in the field.